# Namespaces in the Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Because of the nature of my application, I need to "namespace" the datastore.

This is the code I see in the docs:

```
// Set the namepace temporarily to "abc"
String oldNamespace = NamespaceManager.get();
NamespaceManager.set("abc");
try {
  ... perform operation using current namespace ...
} finally {
  NamespaceManager.set(oldNamespace);
}
```

However, I'm not sure where the namespace must be set to the XML before you can use it or you can create namespace dynamically in code?

Also I see with the `MemcacheService` there is a `setNamespace` method (although deprecated already); how about the `DatastoreService` is there a way to namespace a given service instance we get from the `DatastoreServiceFactory` factory, so we don't have to set namespace back-and-forth with our code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to declare namespaces to use them. If you want to make a multi-tenant application then namespaces are a perfect fit. Basically, you just have to set the namespace **once** at the beginning of your request. That namespace setting automatically applies to all your API calls during that request. Switching back and forth as shown in the docs will only be necessary for accessing data that's **shared** by all tenants.

Comment: how about namespace leaking, have you encountered that?

Comment: No, I haven't encountered namespace leaking. You must beware though of situations where you switch namespaces during a sequence of operations. The docs are not very clear about the exact moment the new namespace settings take effect. Like in: (a) create a query (b) switch namespaces (c) run query. In this case the namespace is bound to the query when it was created not when run. But that will only be a consideration if you work with concurrent transactions spanning multiple namespaces at the same time (which I do). So it's safest to stick with the code pattern you outlined in your question.